# how to redirect home page if only login is success .react js node js with jwt

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, authentication, jwt

I have searched everywhere and I can't find a solution for this.

I have login page react and connect to node js backend. also, connect jwt authentication.

successful came token in console

[image]

but the problem is if login is successful and failed also redirects home page.I want to redirect home page if only login is success

**this is my redirect part**

```
export default function RegisterUser ({history}){

const [Name,setName] = useState("");
const [Email,setEmail] = useState("");
const [Num ,setNum] = useState("");
const [Password,setPassword]=useState("");

const[error,setError] = useState(false);
const[loding,setLoding]=useState(false);
useEffect(()=>{
    
         const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
            
            console.log(userInfo)
        
         if (userInfo){
            history.push("/Home");
         }
},[history])
```

**this is token set part**

```
const getData = async (e)=>{

e.preventDefault();


try {
    const config ={
    headers: {
        "Content-type":"application/json"
    }
}
    setLoding(true);
        const { data } = await  axios.post(

            "http://localhost:8070/Register/login",
            {
                Email,Password,
            },
            config
        );
        console.log(data)
            localStorage.setItem("userInfo",JSON.stringify(data));
            
            setLoding(false);
}catch(error){

    setError(error.response.data.message);
}
```

}

how to redirect only login is success :)

Comment: add some backend code also

Comment: backend is complete. how to redirect home page if login is success

Answer (score 0):

The setItem() function will save the data to your local storage(your pc). even though you refresh the page it will not be erased from the local storage. Make sure before retry login you have removed data from your local storage.
To remove it use localStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
make a button and give a function to it and execute removeItem function.

```
localStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
```

You may use it in you useEffect() method.

```
useEffect(() => { localStorage.removeItem('userInfo')});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (userInfo){
   history.push("/Home");
 }
else {
alert('Please Check');
setEmail('');
//set all the fields to
```